# Real antisymmetric matrix of order 36

Tags: matrix

I have generated a real antisymmetric matrix of order 6 as follows.

```
k0 = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0,
    0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}}
```

Any way to generate such a matrix of order 36 X 36 without writing each terms as above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) to reproduce your example 6-by-6 matrix:

```
m = SparseArray[
  {Band[{1,2},{-1,-1}]->{1,0}, Band[{2,1},{-1,-1}]->{-1,0}}, {6,6}];
AntisymmetricMatrixQ@m (* True *)
```

This simple change from `{6,6}` to `{36,36}` makes a 36-by-36 matrix:

```
m = SparseArray[
  {Band[{1,2},{-1,-1}]->{1,0}, Band[{2,1},{-1,-1}]->{-1,0}}, {36,36}];
AntisymmetricMatrixQ@m (* True *)
```

The matrix is a SparseArray. Use `Normal@m` to create an ordinary list.

Answer (score 8):

This example returns a `SparseArray`.  Use `Normal` to make it a nested list, if you prefer.

```
mat = Block[{b, n = 6},
   b = Riffle[ConstantArray[1, n/2], 0];
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> b, Band[{2, 1}] -> -b}, {n, n}]
   ];
MatrixForm @ mat
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Alternatively,

```
mat = With[{n = 6}, 
 KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n/2], {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}]]
```